# 3D Graphics are dark

Tags: plotting

I have just installed 12.1 and was trying to have a 3D plot. The problem I have is that the color of the 3D plot is very dark (attached figure 1). The color of the graphic will light up only if I click on the plot and try to manipulate it (attached figure 2). I am not sure how to adjust it and I don't think it was a lighting problem. Is it a version 12.1 thing?[image]

[image]

Comment: OS ? Code? etc...?

Comment: Won't be code, because I typed the same code on Wolfram Cloud, the 3D plot is right.

Comment: Hi user6014, do you have 12.1 installed? Is other people's 3D plot on 12.1 normal?

Comment: Can you please edit the requested information into the question (in particular, OS, OS version, graphics hardware)? Otherwise people will not be able to help. No, it is not darker on macOS.

Comment: I can't reproduce locally either (12.1, Windows) so you probably want to contact support@wolfram.com

Comment: I am using mac os 10.15.3, Macbook Prro 16 inch

Comment: I have decided to reinstall...

Comment: @Szabolcs By the way, thank you for the MaTeX tool, it is really handy!

Comment: @yundongren I suggest contacting Wolfram Support directly. If this is an issue specific to your hardware, they will want to know about it, and they will probably ask you for more details. It's a good idea to evaluate `SystemInformation[]` in a fresh kernel and a new notebook, save the notebook, and attach it to your report.

Comment: I'm on macOS 10.14.6, 2017 15-inch MacBook Pro, everything works fine both with the integrated and the discrete GPU.

Comment: I am now reinstalling, will update the results. For now, it seems to me Wolfram Engine or Wolfram Script can generate good 3D graphics, just my frontend somehow messed up.

Comment: Still not working after reinstalling... I have contacted WolframResearch directly for help

Comment: For now, I found that using the lighting option as `Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}` can brighten up the color, but the default don't work.

Comment: This question needs to be reopened.  I contacted Wolfram Support and they have confirmed that this is a issue in MacOS related to the default 'Metal' graphics rendering engine.  Switching it to use OpenGL was recommended as a workaround.

Comment: @heropup can confirm this works

Answer (score 7):

This is a hardware/software issue in the new macOS, I think, and the Metal 3D rendering engine which is now the default.

[This comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216694/3d-graphics-are-dark#comment567427_216694) indicates WRI is aware of the issue.

We can set this option using the `"3DRenderingEngine"` option to [`RenderingOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenderingOptions.html). This can be done via

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  RenderingOptions -> {
    "RenderingEngine" -> <engine>
    }
  ];
```

or done at the `Cell`/`Notebook` level in case WRI patches this for 12.2

Here's what the options do for me

```
Grid@Transpose@Table[
   {
    o,
    Style[
     Graphics3D[{
       Sphere[]
       }],
     RenderingOptions -> {
       "3DRenderingEngine" -> o
       }
     ]
    },
   {o, {Automatic, "Metal", "OpenGL", "Mesa"}}
   ]
```

[image]

`"OpenGL"` is faster than `"Mesa"`, but is Unix only. On the other hand, I think Windows doesn't have this issue, so `"OpenGL"` seems to be the way to go.

I just set

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd,
  RenderingOptions -> {
    "RenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"
    }
  ];
```

so that I don't need to deal with this again until I update Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

I see something similar, under macOS, with:

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Original image]

I think it's just a matter of the direction of the light source(s).

Rotating the plot manually with the mouse, or changing the `ViewPoint` will lighten the plot.

[image: Rotated image]

Comment: It is not the `ViewPoint` I have determined that it is a problem related to the external monitor. Without connecting to my monitor (Dell S2716DG) it works fine, once it is connected, the color is dark.

Comment: I have changed to another monitor, the problem persists.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do have this problem when connected to external monitor?

Answer (score 1):

You might try to play with the `Lighting` option. For example, like this:

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Point", Yellow, {-4, -5, 8}}}]
```

[image]

and try to play with the position of the point light source.

Another possibility is the "Neutral" light source

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

or a "Directional" one

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
    RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.3], {{5, 5, 7}, {5, 9, 0}}}}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Plotting with Lighting -> {White} gets rid of part of the problem. Namely, when clicked on and moved, the lighting looks no different than when the mouse is not used. Unfortunately, the lighting is so diffuse that the shading is also removed, but at least one can see the surface equally well in all positions.

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Lighting -> {White}]
```

[image]

Next, let us compromise with another lighting trick; Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}, {"Point", Brown, {1, 1, 1}}}], and remember, this only pertains to a newer Mac with Mathematica 12.1. This is now somewhat different when dragged and still, but at least is is not so dark as to have no contrast.

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}, {"Point", Brown, {1, 1, 1}}}]
```

[image]

Putting in multiple point light sources still shows different coloring while being rotated than when there is no mouse capture, but at least one can then see the object better at rest:

```
Plot3D[Sin[1.75 (x + y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Lighting -> {{"Point", Brown, Scaled[{2, 0, 0}]}, {"Point", Orange, 
Scaled[{0, -2, 0}]}, {"Point", Orange, Scaled[{0, 0, 2}]}}]
```

[image]

Other solution, use an old copy of Mathematica, e.g., v10.3
[image]

Comment: Definitely yours should be chosen as a main answer. Thanks